# Запятая, интересная очень-таки

Tags: запятые

Нужна запятая?

`Утром покорми черепаху, кота, осминога(,) и вечером, когда будет полуполная луна, отъезжай на дачонку.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно:

***Утром** покорми черепаху, кота, осьминога, **и вечером**, когда будет полуполная луна, отъезжай на дачонку.*

Грамматика предложения действительно **интересная**: однородный ряд дополнений, односоставные предложения, соединенные союзом И, придаточное времени в середине второго предложения.

Здесь **три предикативные** основы  (два односоставных предложения и придаточное времени), поэтому решаем задачу **методом блоков**.

Граница между блоками проходит перед соединительным **союзом И,** связь сочинительная, обозначаем ее **запятой**.

С точки зрения семантики здесь два сообщения, обозначенных обстоятельствами времени (утром и вечером).

***P. S.***

**Другой знак?** Я выбирала между **запятой и тире**, но тире обозначает **присоединительную** конструкцию. Мне показалось, что запятой **достаточно**.

Comment: Но там же-с два предложения повелительные, а в РАН написано, что, если так, запятая не ставится.

Comment: А где именно так написано? С односоставными предложениями постоянно возникают проблемы.

Comment: В 5-м пункте написано про то, если обе части – побудительные: http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133.

Comment: В нашем случае нет восклицательного знака и частиц, то есть нет ничего объединяющего.

Answer (score 2):

Лучше, по-моему, вместо запятой в проблемном месте поставить тире или точку:

***Утром покорми черепаху, кота, осьминога** — и вечером, когда будет полуполная луна, отъезжай на дачонку.*

***Утром покорми черепаху, кота, осьминога**.  И вечером, когда будет полуполная луна, отъезжай на дачонку.*

ИМХО.

Comment: На мой взгляд, с такими знаками предложение проще читается. При постановке же запятой перед «и» можно споткнуться на таком его прочтении:

_**Утром покорми черепаху, кота, осьминога, и вечером**, // когда будет полуполная луна, отъезжай на дачонку._